Specify minimum OS version in Package.swift
I'm trying to specify the minimum OS version using the platforms field in Package.swift, but I'm getting an error:
$ swift package init --type=executable
$ vim Package.swift
$ swift build
error: manifest parse error(s):
/Users/user/Testing/Package.swift:6:22: error: incorrect argument label in call (have 'name:platforms:dependencies:targets:', expected 'name:pkgConfig:dependencies:targets:')
let package = Package(
                     ^

Package.swift:
// swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Testing",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v10_12)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "Testing",
        )
    ]
)


You want to update this line:
// swift-tools-version:4.0

You likely want 5.10 here, though you might want a somewhat older version if you want to support all the way back to 10.12 (do you really mean that? Do you really mean 12?). Make sure you've updated your Swift install. Note that the above Package.swift isn't even syntactically legal, so I would go back to the one automatically generated by swift.
If you really are looking for 10.12, then you need to go back to tools level 5.4, which also requires a slightly different layout (so you would need to pass path: if you are using the layout created by the current tools):
// swift-tools-version:5.4
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Testing",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v10_12)
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
        .executableTarget(
            name: "Testing",
            path: "Sources"),
    ]
)

If you mean macOS 12 (.v12), then you can use a later version of the tools (up to 5.10) and don't need to reorganize your tree or pass a path: parameter.

I'm running on some very old hardware, so I am using Sierra which I believe is 10.12.  My swift tools version is 4.0, but I'll see if I can update.
